# Spring security Authentication with roles error and how to solve it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

i am trying to login with USER and ADMIN roles each accessing /user and /admin using spring security

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

        @Bean
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }

        @Bean
        UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
            UserDetails user = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

            UserDetails admin = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode("password"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

            return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user, admin);
        }
        
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
            MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
            http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/home")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/admin")).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/user")).hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

when accessing /home it works fine but when accessing /user and /admin it gives forbidden 403 error why does it behave like this and how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you miss `http.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());` to add before `return http.build();`

Answer (score -1):

add formLogin as below

```
   @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, HandlerMappingIntrospector introspector) throws Exception {
            MvcRequestMatcher.Builder mvcMatcherBuilder = new MvcRequestMatcher.Builder(introspector);
            http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/home")).permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/admin")).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(mvcMatcherBuilder.pattern("/user")).hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
            return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
        }
```